# convert an android project into a library project

Tags: java, android

I need some help to convert an android project into library project.

I wanna convert e.g simpleMjpeg project into library project. Can u help me to solve this.

Edit:

I din't mean this:

Right click on project -> property -> Android -> check 'Is library' check box -> OK.

Android project contains resources files and .java files. Is it possible to make a `jar` with the android project.

Comment: what do you mean by real api library? and if you edit your question put it under the edit section keeping the previous part.

Comment: @Raghunandan:
Thank you.
but i want to convert into api library.

Comment: You can package pure java files that do not refer to resources as a jars. you cannot package resource files into jars.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects. check this

Comment: pls elaborate and explain clearly what you need whether your project has resource files or pure java files..

Comment: project has both the resource files and pure java files.

Comment: then packaging into jar is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am going to modify my java files without using res files.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your android project. goto properties. Choose Android. Make sure you check Is Library check box. Your project is now a library project. You can refer the same in another android project.

For more information

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Check the topic under setting up library project.

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Edit:

It is not possible to package resources files into jar. You can package pure java files that do not refer to resources as jar file.